# Can't post array back to action method mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to post an array of values back to my action method, but with no luck as I'm getting a null for 'ParcelList'. Upload Files argument is being populated, just having a problem with ParcelList.

```
//ParcelList returning null
 public ActionResult Add(AddShipmentVM model, ParcelVM[] ParcelList, HttpPostedFileBase[] UploadFiles )
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Home", "CustomClearence");
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

ParcelVM

```
 public class ParcelVM
 {
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(AddShipmentVM), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredValue")]
    public string TrackTrace { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(AddShipmentVM), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredValue")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\d{0,3}\.?(\d{3,3})*,?\d{1,2}$", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(AddShipmentVM), ErrorMessageResourceName = "InvalidWeight")]
    public string GrossWeight { get; set; }

    public decimal Parcelno { get; set; }
 }
```

**Ajax**
When user clicks on finish, submit form

```
 $(".actions a[href=#finish]").click(function () {

            var form = jQuery('#addShipmentForm').serializeObject();


            var parcelList = $.parseJSON(ko.toJSON(viewModel.parcelList()));
            var tariffList = $.parseJSON(ko.toJSON(viewModel.tariffList()));
            var dashBoardurl = '@Url.Action("Home","Shipment")'


            var tariffObject = JSON.stringify({ TariffList: tariffList });
    $('#uploadDocument input[type=file]')[0].files }
            var UploadFiles = { UploadFiles: $('#uploadDocument input[type=file]')[0].files }
            $.extend(form, { FinancialAndCustomsModel: tariffObject });
            $.extend(form, { ParcelList: parcelList });
            $.extend(form, UploadFiles);


            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: form,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.status == "success") {
                        $(location).attr('href', dashBoardurl);
                    }
                    else {
                        //$(location).attr('href', addRequestUrl);
                    }

                },
                cache: false,
                processData: false

            });
       });
```

Comment: IIRC, you need to use `traditional:true` option for your `$.ajax` call when posting to an action.

Comment: I added traditional to the ajax call but no luck. I tried JSON.stringify({ ParcelList: parcelList }); but no luck

Comment: Let jQuery covert the objects. Currently you have a hybrid of JSO and JSON. just simply pass one or the other.

Comment: The data being sent in the post request, is not ParcelList array of objects, but rather iteration of each property of every item in that ParcelList. Why am i getting this?